# PostgreSQL: Assign generated password in CREATE ROLE

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to setup a DB initialization script. I need to avoid manual configuration steps AND hardcoded passwords in the source code. I have a function which generates random passwords (adapted from https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/46685BBD.3070809@hagander.net).

The function works (e.g. `select generate_random_password()`), but I cannot get the "CREATE ROLE" command to accept anything except raw strings.

Does anyone know how I can set the password with the return value of a function that's already been declared? Do I need to mess around with `EVALUATE` (like a shell-script using `eval`)?

This:

```
CREATE ROLE my_user WITH LOGIN CREATEDB PASSWORD generate_random_password();
```

Yields: `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "generate_random_password"`

This:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    passwd varchar := generate_random_password();
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'my_user') THEN
        CREATE ROLE my_user WITH LOGIN CREATEDB PASSWORD passwd;
    END IF;
END
$$;
```

Yields: `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "passwd" Position: 208`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need dynamic SQL:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    passwd varchar := generate_random_password();
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'my_user') THEN
        EXECUTE FORMAT(
          'CREATE ROLE my_user WITH LOGIN CREATEDB PASSWORD %L', passwd
        );
    END IF;
END
$$;
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I can't thank you enough. I was banging my head trying to figure out a technique.